# Javascript Regex Pattern "{{text}}"

Tags: javascript, regex

I stuck with code regex pattern for javascript. i want to validate this string {{text}. But still not working.
For c# its working find. here is code for c#

```
"{{[^\{\s}]+\}}"
```

i want start with {{ end with }}. in between can be text or number

Comment: Anyways.. I think just `var arrayResults = myString.match(/{{.*?}}/g);` is superior: _https://regex101.com/r/xI2gP9/1_

Comment: Also, what are you trying to achieve? And, why regex? .. Maybe there are others true parse methods that could find brackets inside brackets, thing that regex can't do.

Comment: And why would `{{text}` match against a regular expression that expects **two** closing curly brackets?

Comment: @Ultimater Read the last sentence where he appears to correct the typo.  I think the ultimate problem was with using `[^{\s}]` to match text or numbers, which invites problems.

Comment: I think his problem is he's using a string `"{{[^\{\s}]+\}}"` which loads as the string `{{[^{s}]+}}` in JavaScript's internal memory, and probably passing it to RegExp. So he'd need to double escape if this were the case. Or he'd need to replace the double quotes with forward slashes for an instant regular expression rather than constructing one from a string sent to RegExp.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem with your regular expression is you're treating it as a string and your backslashes are getting lost in the process.  If you type `"{{[^\{\s}]+\}}"` into an alert, you'll see it displays `{{[^{s}]+}}` thus losing all your backslashes. If you'd like to preserve the backslashes, you'll need to double escape it: `"{{[^\\{\\s}]+\}}"` That is assuming, you're sending it to RegExp like so `RegExp("{{[^\\{\\s}]+\}}")`. This is fine, but it's the same as saying `/{{[^\{\s}]+}}/` which is JavaScript's literal syntax for constructing a regular expression. Thus you'd do:

```
var reg1=RegExp("{{[^\\{\\s}]+\}}");
var reg2=/{{[^\{\s}]+}}/;
reg1.test('{{text}}');//true
reg2.test('{{text}}');//true
```

You can also write it as a single line: `/{{[^\{\s}]+}}/.test('{{text}}')`
There's a few regular expression methods out there for JavaScript, some work on a string and expect you to send it a regular expression and some accept a regular expression and expect a string. So be careful in the order you send your string and regular expression to the methods out there.

Answer (score 4):

Try this regex:

```
^\{\{[\d\w]+\}\}$
```

It makes more sense to me to explicitly match any number of characters or numbers rather than trying to match anything which excludes whitespace.  Your original regex would match `{{@}}` which I don't think you want.

[**Regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/nF9pL2/2)

Update:

As @Washington pointed out, brackets are not special characters in JavaScript and therefore you should *not* need to escape them.  Then it would seem that the problem you instead had was in how you were matching.

Comment: BTW, if you haven't made regular use of the tool at Tim's link, I highly recommend it.  While debugging regexp in the console is fine, the contextual info provided by **Regex101** does an excellent job of showing what each bit of your expression does.  It's one of my favorite online tools.